# Register For Both Local And Remote Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

THis is how we register for local notification

```
if UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))  {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound], categories: nil));
}
```

How do we do the same for remote? **Is there a way where we can register once and work for both?**

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper function to register for both at the same time:

```
func initializeNotificationServices() {
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings) //Local notifications

    // This is an asynchronous method to retrieve a Device Token. You have to implement callbacks in AppDelegate to use the device token.
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```